# laravel's eloquent returns all records instead of one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model, eloquent

This is really strange, but.. here is situation:

In my controller I have return with a call to model like this:

```
return $modelName->someMethod($param1, $param2);
```

in that someMethod I have call to another model, e.g:

```
public function someMethod($param1, $param2) {
    $var = OtherModel::find(1);
    // ...
}
```

And no matter what I do, `$var` always returns all records from `OtherModel`, instead of searching by primary key and returning only one entry. It doesn't matter if I call `->first()` or not. Upon instantiation, e.g `$var = OtherModel;`, `$var` is already filled with all records from `OtherModel`.

Can anyone give me explanation why is this happening or maybe some hints where I went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't matter that I have call to another model from model. Tried calling straight from controller. Same results. `SomeModel::find(1);` return all records from that model. What the..?

Comment: Unless you are overrinding the `find` method in `OtherModel`, you should be getting only one row or be empty if no matches are found. Your example is kind of generic, perhaps the problem lies somewhere else in your code, and without a actual example of your code it might be difficult to help.

Comment: Show the execution and its result. You're doing something wrong, that's for sure.